# dependent jar is not bundled along with project jar Gradle

Tags: gradle, jar

I have a project `corehibernate` and a project `coregeneral`. `corehibernate` is dependent on `coregeneral`. I need the jar file of `coregeneral` to be bundled along with the `corehibernate` jar. I tried various versions of the `build.gradle` thing, nothing worked.

I tried `compile files("../coregeneral/build/libs/coregeneral.jar")`

This version of fatJar too does not work.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile (':coregeneral')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
    baseName='corehibernate'
    from ('bin')
}

task fatJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: jar) {
  baseName = project.name + '-fat'
}
```

Comment: 'Shadow jar' plugin can do that - http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/

Comment: I dont want an executable jar, I need a library jar.

Comment: You don't have to use it as an executable. The only difference is an entry in the manifest file.

Comment: Your fatJar task doesn't do anything except give the jar a new name. See here: https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways how to bundle projects together. The first would be to use [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) which creates a zip with scripts that will also execute your application and bundle all jars by default. Second way is to use [distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) and define the final archive yourself (zip or tar).

Here is a sample project using the application plugin:

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'root'
include 'partone', 'parttwo'
```

**build.gradle**

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

**partone/build.gradle** - this one is empty

**parttwo/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'Hello'

dependencies {
    compile project (':partone')
}
```

Give that both projects actually have some content (classes), when you run `gradle :projecttwo:build` it will generate a zip file with executable scripts and both jars bundled inside.

If you prefer to use distribution plugin, change the **parttwo/build.gradle** to:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from jar
            from (project.configurations.runtime)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project (':partone')
}
```

And again run `gradle :parttwo:build`. It will create a zip file that contains both jars.